# SceneKit DAE animation not appearing in attributes

Tags: scenekit, collada, caanimation

I'm trying to carefully word this question because the problem doesn't appear to be that the animation isn't being imported. I can see the animation as `<untitled animation>` in the scene graph, and I can play the animation in Xcode; the issue is then locating the animation as an attribute to any of the objects. This is what I can see in the scene graph:
[image: scene graph]

But, when I try and locate the animation here:

[image]

... nothing appears. So, it seems that it isn't importing the animation as a `CAAnimation` object with a key.

I have tried to programmatically enumerate through the child nodes to find any `CAAnimation` objects, but it doesn't see any. Other scenes work perfectly however.

What do I need to add to the DAE file to get it to build the `CAAnimation` object properly?

Worth pointing out that the 3D model and animation was exported from 3DS Max using OpenCollada. I don't know what the best practices are for exporting collada to SceneKit, and if anyone has any useful information that would be great. Apple don't seem to have anything.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful in your case, but I had something similar and solved it by not dragging the files into Xcode, but right click on art.scnassets and 'Add files to 'art.scnassets'. After that I could access it in VCs.

Comment: note that the root node isn't displayed in the scene graph view, it might be the one that holds the animation. Does your code also check the root node?

Comment: That’s a good point! Will check.

Comment: I was able to find the animation on the root and then set the usesSceneTimeBase to false to get it to play. No idea how to find this root node in the Xcode SceneKit editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SceneKit editor in Xcode does not display the root node in the scene graph view, and it might be the one that holds the animation.

You should be able to retrieve the root node's animation programmatically.